# Why can I not implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'float'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reset an object's position on my main menu screen without reloading the scene. However, I am getting this error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'float') when attempting to reset the velocity and angular velocity of the falling object.

I have tried replacing the 'Vector2.zero' part to just '0f' and to a float that is equal to 0f but it also didn't work.

```
void Update () {
        transform.Translate (Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        if (player.transform.position.x >= 13f) {
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = Vector2.zero;
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().angularVelocity = Vector2.zero;
            player.transform.position = new Vector2 (-8.5f, 6f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know unity, but just looked in the docs, and [`angularVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-angularVelocity.html) is a `float`, so the above code would need to be changed on that line (but not the line above that one, since [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) is a [`Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = Vector2.zero;
```

`angularVelocity` is a float, not a vector. You're trying to pass a pair of values where the compiler can only use one, so it doesn't understand what you want to do.

You can assign `0f` instead:

```
player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = 0f;
```

Comment: Thank you that has sorted the problem